# Accessing Filemaker value lists through ODBC

Tags: odbc, filemaker

I'm building a .Net Web application and my data needs to be in Filemaker. Using ODBC I'm working just fine with data stored in tables. But I need also to obtain value lists data. ¿Is this possible in any way?
Thanxs in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure doesn't look like it.

FileMaker has two types of Value Lists: those that are dynamically generated you should be able to re-create in ODBC with some equivalent queries.

To get a static value list, though, you'd need the ability to change FileMaker. Depending on your needs, you might consider either:

1. Make a new table and have each record be a value list item. Then the Value List could show the records from that table dynamically and you could query for the contents of the table with ODBC, or
2. You could make a new calculated field which simply lists a value list's items using code like:

   ValueListItems ( Get ( FileName ) ; **ValueListName** )